# Arduino vscode: identifier "sprintf" is undefined

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, arduino-ide

I just installed the `vscode-arduino` plugin for VSCode, because I would really like to stop working in that horrible IDE. While setting it up, I ran into a couple problems, one of them required me to downgrade the installed arduino IDE to version 1.8.6, and the other required me to add defines: USBCON to my c_cpp_properties.json. Here are all the files in my `.vscode` folder:

`arduino.json`

```
{
    "board": "arduino:avr:nano",
    "configuration": "cpu=atmega328old",
    "sketch": "EEPROM_Programmer.ino"
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": [
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools\\**",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\**",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\**"
      ],
      "forcedInclude": [
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino\\Arduino.h"
      ],
      "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
      "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "defines": ["USBCON"]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions, they would be appreciated!

Comment: Answering the title - if you want to use `sprintf`, then include `stdio.h` from the AVR standard library.

Comment: I have tried that, but that doesn't fix the problem. This is actually a problem from the vscode-arduino extension I believe, because when I compile it, it doesn't throw any errors. This also started happening with SPI, and direct port access variables like PINB, PORTB, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have had some similar problems with VS Code IntelliSense for Arduino.

Somehow, IntelliSense does not work with the Visual Studio compiler. I have changed the following settings inside the `c_cpp_properties.json` file to use the compiler which is provided by Arduino.

Old:

```
"intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
"compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe"
```

New:

```
"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
"compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\bin\\avr-gcc.exe"
```

Maybe you have to adjust the path to your Arduino folder.

This change solved my problems with the undefined identifier.